# При парсинге xml файла html теги не обрабатываются

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, почему у меня при парсинге xml документа на JS все html теги вставляются текстом. В итоге получаем: `Тря-ля-ля <b>Ло-ло</b>` Хотя Ло-ло должно жирным выводится.

UPD.
Парсим xml файл проектов. Описание такое в xml 
    <opisanie_projekta>Этот &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;дом&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt; запланирован в форме квадрата и очень простой по конструкции. Предусмотрено несколько вариантов технологий при строительстве наружных стен. &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Проекты домов&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt; доступны также в зеркальном отображении.</opisanie_projekta>

Код парсера:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "pg.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

var globaltext
function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();
    $find = $(xml).find('grupa_proektow[nazwanie=doma]'); // Вытаскиваем все объекты типа "Дома"
    // Производим поиск внутри категории "Дома"
    $find.find("proekt[id=85]").each(function () {      
        $(this).find("type_nr").each(function(i,elem) {
    if($(this).text() == 18) {
           var text = $(this).parent().find("link_fajla").text()
           globaltext = text;
        }

});
var desc = $(this).find("opisanie_projekta").html()
function strip_tags(desc){  // Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string
    // 
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)

    desc =  desc.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
}

    $(".main").append('<div class="left"><div class="book"><div class="title"><strong>' + $(this).find("nazwanie_proekta").text() + '</strong></div><div class="foto"><img src="' + globaltext + '"></div><div class="cubatura">Площадь ' + $(this).find("kubatura").text() + ' м<sup>2</sup></div><div class="date">Код проекта: ' + $(this).find("kod_proekta").text() + '</div></div><div class="book1"><div class="description">' + $(this).find("opisanie_projekta").html() + '</div></div></div><div class="right"><h3>Характеристики проекта</h3></div>');
    $(".left").fadeIn(1000); 
    $(".book").fadeIn(1000);    
    $(".book1").fadeIn(1000);   
    $(".right").fadeIn(2000);

    });

$('img').attr({ width: 600 });

}
```

Я тут пытался использовать strip_tags - безрезультатно. Интересует desc.

Comment: Ну уверен, но попробуйте использовать innerHTML вместо innerText

Comment: Получилась такая вещь: &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Ло-ло&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;

Comment: @Batyabest, дополните вопрос подробностями. Как и что парсите, что в консоле, что в коде страницы.

Comment: Я слегка упростил, и вот что у меня [получилось](http://jsfiddle.net/3nfu5c5h/)

Comment: Сильный ход! Особенно если учитывать, что слегка упростил)) Подскажи, где мне в моем коде поправить)

Comment: $.parseXML(xml); применять не надо было. `dataType: "xml"` указано, значить все само распарсится. Ваш код не поправлять, а рефакторить надо.